# What is the phenomenon that each word variation is regarded equally, not a variation of the root?

Tags: morphology, psycholinguistics, cognitive-linguistics

This is a thing that I remember that I read in a cognitive psychology book, but I can't find it out. For example, the word `cats` has two morphemes: `cat` + `s`. So we usually regard `cats` as a [morphological derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation) of `cat`, with the formula: if there are many `cat`, change it to `cats`. However, we process `cat` and `cats` equally. That is, `cats` is stored in your memory as if it's a standalone word, not a derivation of `cat`. When you need to use the word, you pull `cats` immediately, not rerun the formula.

This seems to fit with the [dual process theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_process_theory) (commonly know as the fast and slow thinking). For introduction, watch [The Science of Thinking - Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBVV8pch1dM)

What is the name of this phenomenon?

Comment: "However, we process cat and cats equally. That is, cats is stored in your memory as if it's a standalone word, not a derivation of cat." How do you know this?

Comment: The classic "wug test" seems to poke a hole in that theory: children acquire productive rules, not just tables of examples. Besides, given that words like _parimunngauniralauqsimanngittunga_ "I never said that I wanted to go to Paris" are attested in various languages (that one's Inuktitut), I'd be very surprised if anyone seriously claimed all words were stored as separate units.

Comment: (Or is the claim instead that for certain, commonly-used words, we store the forms as separate lexemes, hence irregularities like is~are?)

Comment: @curiousdannii "This is a thing that I remember that I read in a cognitive psychology book, but I can't find it out."

Comment: @Draconis cognitively speaking, this claim seems legit with the dual process theory. Watch [The Science of Thinking - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBVV8pch1dM "The Science of Thinking - YouTube")

Comment: Yes, it definitely sounds like you want to follow up on 20th century lexical models: ‘full-listing’, ‘dual-listing’/‘dual-route', ‘parsed’/‘decomposed’, etc. Here are some refs from a paper I had at hand (Waksler 1999): "Full-listing models (e.g., Butterworth, 1983; Dell & O’Seaghdha, 1992)”, "Parsed models (e.g., Taft & Forster, 1975; Taft, 1994)”. Note that ‘dual route’ is often/(primarily) used for reading & phonological theories, so that can muddy your searches.

Comment: The claim, as I understand it, is that even though we have the ability to compose novel words like "wugs", once we do so, we store them and retrieve them as a whole piece rather than actually applying the rules each time we decide to say "wugs".

Comment: @user6726 yes, that correct. Do you find my wording unclear?

Comment: Some of the other comments seemed to think otherwise.

Comment: @user6726 what you mean by "otherwise"? My question is unclear? Or my question has a false premise?

Comment: @ooker You may want to specify whether you are really talking about derivation or inflection. In your example of cat and cats, you're referring to inflection, not derivation. Derivations, such as unlock from lock, are more likely to have separate lemma in memory than inflections, like locks from lock, at least in a spreading activation model. However, according to Lemma Theory (Levelt, 1989), every word is stored separately with semantic and syntactic information stored together, and only phonological information, and not inflections, are added in production.